# How to export the view data in excel file and adding color for particular column

Tags: php, view, drupal-7, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I have created a view in drupal 7 and i want to export the view data into csv/excel format. I am able to export the data using "view data exporter" module. But i want to add the red color for one column during export.

Please guide me if there is any module exist in drupal who have such functionality or please provide me custom solution for that.